# How to handle security.enable-csrf in Spring Boot 2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm migrating an application from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0.5.
I have a property set as `security.enable-csrf=true` in 1.5 version which is not available in 2.0 version of Spring Boot.

I read the documents and it is said that in Spring Boot 2.0:

> CSRF protection is enabled by default in the Java configuration.

So by default it is enabled ok fine, but there is also one class created which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` this means Spring Boot default security configuration has been turned off. Is this also means `security.enable-csrf` is disabled now?

If yes how do I enable it like I had it in the application for 1.5 version.

I didn't get any document which gives a clear confirmation on how to handle `security.enable-csrf` property in Spring Boot 2.0 and while declaring the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Does anyone know about it? Also any document link which I have missed to read about this would be great help.

Comment: If you only extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` without disabling the defaults it is stil on. The Spring Boot available extension to `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will only kick in if there is no other `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` found. The Spring Boot default class does nothing more then use the Spring Security defaults (it is an empty implementation).

Answer (score 7):

In order to have backward compatibility with the property already been set in you application, `security.enable-csrf=true`, you can use the following code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${security.enable-csrf}")
    private boolean csrfEnabled;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (!csrfEnabled) {
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

> As you might guess the magic comes from `http.csrf().disable();` that
>   in the above code you can control enabling/disabling it by the
>   property you have set in you application.properties file.

---

**More Info:**

For more details you can also refer to the spring documents:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf

Answer (score 0):

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is an abstract class, when you create a class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you will override `void configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.

You can disable csrf in this method, like that;

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

You can read this comment on top of the `csrf()` method (in `HttpSecurity` class).

> Adds CSRF support. This is activated by default when using
>   `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`'s default constructor. You can disable it ...."

This comment says that, when you extends this class, default constructor of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` works and csrf is activated.